Python Concurrent Futures not taking the data out of memory
I am working on Python code that copies tables of 50+ GB from PostgreSQL to SQL server and creates tables dynamically. Copies the data using SQLAlchemy Streaming and batch insert using Concurrent ThreadPoolExecutor. Each thread creating its own connection (same connection for multiple insert running into SQL server busy)
I noticed that the code runs fine for 5-10 GB tables but starting running out of memory for other huge tables. When plotting the memory usage of Python code, I noticed that the memory usage keeps climbing.

Cod snippet in main:
for table in tables:
    table_name = table[0]
    print("table :", table_name)
    # Connect to PostgreSQL
    pg_conn = psycopg2.connect(host=pg_server, port=pg_port, database=pg_db, user=pg_user, password=pg_password)
    pg_cursor = pg_conn.cursor()
    # Get column names and datatypes from PostgreSQL
    pg_cursor.execute(f"SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = %s AND table_name = %s", (schema_name, table_name))
    pg_columns = pg_cursor.fetchall()
    pg_cursor.close()
    pg_conn.close()

    # Connect to SQL Server
    sql_conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + sql_server + ';DATABASE=' + sql_db + ';UID=' + sql_user + ';PWD=' + sql_password)
    sql_cursor = sql_conn.cursor()

    sq_columns = [(column[0], dtmapping[column[1]]) for column in pg_columns]
    sq_column_definitions = ', '.join([f"[{column[0]}] {column[1]}" for column in sq_columns])
    sq_cols = [column[0] for column in sq_columns]
    def casting(column):
        if column[1] in ['json','bjson']:
            return f'"{column[0]}"::text as "{column[0]}"'
        else:
            return f'"{column[0]}"'
    column_names = [casting(column) for column in pg_columns] 
    column_names_str = ', '.join(column_names)
    if schema_name == 'public':
        schema_name = 'dbo'
    # Create schema and table in SQL Server
    sql_cursor.execute(f"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name='{schema_name}') BEGIN EXEC('CREATE SCHEMA [{schema_name}]') END")
    sql_cursor.execute(f"IF NOT EXISTS (Select * from information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME ='{table_name}' and TABLE_SCHEMA = '{schema_name}' AND TABLE_type = 'BASE TABLE') BEGIN CREATE TABLE [{schema_name}].[{table_name}] ({sq_column_definitions}) END")
    sql_cursor.execute(f"TRUNCATE TABLE {schema_name}.{table_name}")

    # Commit the changes
    sql_conn.commit()
    sql_cursor.close()
    sql_conn.close()

    def yieldmany(exe,chunk_size,chunk_cnt):
        while 'batch not empty':
            batch = exe.fetchmany(chunk_size)
            if not batch:
                break
            chunk_cnt += 1
            yield pd.DataFrame(batch) , chunk_cnt
    
    #Connect to postgres using SQLAlchemy Source
    enginer = create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://{pg_user}:{pg_password}@{pg_server}/{pg_db}',echo=False, echo_pool=False, pool_pre_ping=True)
    enginer.execution_options(stream_results=True)
    sqlar_conn = enginer.connect()
    
    print(f"SELECT {column_names_str} FROM {schema_name}.{table_name} limit 1000")
    query = text(f"SELECT {column_names_str} FROM {schema_name}.{table_name}")
    total_chunks = 0
    chunk_cnt = 0
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
        futuress = [executor.submit(worker, chunk, table_name, schema_name,sq_cols,chunk_cnt) for chunk, chunk_cnt in yieldmany(enginer.connect().execution_options(stream_results=True).execute(query),chunk_size,chunk_cnt)]
        for future in futures.as_completed(futuress):
            result, chunk_cnt = future.result()
            del futuress[future]
            total_chunks += chunk_cnt
            print(result)
            
    print(f'{table_name} completed')
    completed_tables.add(table_name)
    logger.info(f'completed tables : {completed_tables}')
    if schema_name == 'dbo':
        schema_name = 'public'
    chunk_cnt = 0
    sqlar_conn.close()
    # exe.close()
    enginer.dispose()

Worker node:
def worker(chunk: pd.DataFrame, table_name: str, schema_name: str, sq_cols: list, chunk_cnt: int):
    logger.info(f'chunking {chunk_cnt} part for {table_name} started')
    engine_url = f'mssql+pyodbc://{sql_user}:{sql_password}@{sql_server}/{sql_db}?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'
    with create_engine(engine_url).connect() as sqlaw_conn:
        sqlaw_conn.execution_options(autocommit=True)
        try:
            chunk.to_sql(table_name, sqlaw_conn, schema=schema_name, if_exists='append', index=False)
            logger.info(f"{table_name} {chunk_cnt} chunked")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error inserting data: {e}")
            problem_tables.add(table_name)
            logger.info(f"Error inserting data for {table_name}: {e}")
            logger.error(f'problem tables : {problem_tables}')
            print("problem_tables : {}".format(problem_tables))
    logger.info(f'problem tables : {problem_tables}')
    return f"{table_name} {chunk_cnt} chunked", chunk_cnt

I tried changing the code to eliminate any lists that might have stored the data fetches and explictly deleting a thread future after its done executing but it doesn't seem to fix the memory overflow.

Using multiple threads can speed up the process, having too many can also increase memory usage. Try reducing the number of threads. Make sure that the chunks fetched from PostgreSQL are processed and released promptly to avoid keeping large amounts of data in memory.

I have tried reducing the threads to 3 and the data chunk size is around 5MB max. Still running out of memory.

Tell me if am wrong but are you just trying to move data from one place to another? Is it all happening through APIs or you are doing some processing of your own as well? Because if these are just API calls you can use asyncIO instead right? I mean it uses a single thread, so it can solve your memory problem cant it?

@Spidy, No these are not API calls

It looks like this is the problem portion of your code
futuress = [executor.submit(worker, chunk, table_name, schema_name, sq_cols, chunk_cnt) 
            for chunk, chunk_cnt in yieldmany(enginer.connect().execution_options(stream_results=True).execute(query), chunk_size, chunk_cnt)]

You can change the above to:
futures = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for chunk, chunk_cnt in yieldmany(enginer.connect().execution_options(stream_results=True).execute(query), chunk_size, chunk_cnt):
        future = executor.submit(worker, chunk, table_name, schema_name, sq_cols, chunk_cnt)
        futures.append(future)
        
        # Process completed futures
        done, not_done = wait(futures, timeout=0, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for future in done:
            result, chunk_cnt = future.result()
            total_chunks += chunk_cnt
            print(result)
            futures.remove(future)

    # Process any remaining futures
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        result, chunk_cnt = future.result()
        total_chunks += chunk_cnt
        print(result)

If the worker takes longer to process than the yieldmany function, you will accumulate DataFrames into memory.

I have replaced the portion of my code with yours but the problem still exists and I did not notice any change in memory usage pattern.
